# The simplest way to create a set of jquery object s

Tags: jquery, object, set

Yeah, the way I was doing is

```
   A.add(B).add(C).add(D).show()
```

While A,B,C,D are jQuery objects. I wonder if there's such a simpler way to do this out there?
I've tried all the following approaches, but no results:

```
$(A,B,C,D).show()
A.add(B,C,D).show()
```

All suggestions are welcome!

---

Addition to clarify the question:

The part ".show()" is just for demonstration. I just wanted to know how could I create a set of JQuery object like $('p') create a set of p tag.

In my real case, I used

```
$([A,B,C,D]).each(fn)
```

instead of .show() (And I wonder why this worked?)
It's obviously that

```
$([A,B,C,D]).each(fn)
$('p').each(fn)
```

both work. But

```
$([A,B,C,D]).show()  //--doesn't work
$('p').show()        //--works
```

Just the second line works. Does anyone know the diffrence between them ?
(I just thought they're the same, then made a bit of tangle in my question)

Comment: Have you tried the documentation? - http://api.jquery.com/add/

Comment: Have you tried `$([A,B,C,D]).show()`?

Comment: @namuol : I didn't think it was that simple, thankyou so much ! Could u pls make ur comment an answer & I'll accept it ? (for others to  find it easily)

Comment: @namuol - nope, doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/Jb6VD/

Comment: @nrabinowitz: Excellent point. I guess I misunderstood; I thought `A,B,C,D` were DOM elements.

Comment: @vantrung-cuncon - as @namuol asked, are `A,B,C,D` DOM elements? If so, then that answer is correct - but I'm quite interested in the same question if they are jQuery objects.

Comment: @vantrung-cuncon: are you sure you have actual jQuery objects? See my answer below for an explanation.

Comment: If A, B, C and D are jQuery objects, then ` A.add(B).add(C).add(D).show()` is the documented way to combine multiple jQuery objects.  One could extract the DOM elements from each, combine them into one array and then give that to a jQuery constructor, but that's more work than the `.add()` method so no point.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$.each([A,B,C,D], function(){ 
    $(this).css('background','red'); 
})
```

Instead of using a selector this solution uses a jQuery method called [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) which takes an array and iterates over it. The array passed is a set of jQuery objects. `$(this)` referes to the jQuery objects being iterated on each time.

**demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/SCjMc/1/

---

### Other facts about how $() works:

`$(element)` is an shortcut for `jQuery(element)`. The `jQuery()` method accepts a different set of parameters:

[image]

The description for each type of parameter can be found in [this link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).

One of the type of parameters is "elementArray". The description for this is:

> **elementArray** An array containing a set of DOM elements to wrap in a jQuery object.

The catch is that when you use jQuery to select an element this returns a jQuery object and not a DOM Element directly. Therefore this will **not** return any elements:

```
var element1 = $("selector1");
var element2 = $("selector2");
$([element1,element2]) // will not return any elements
```

To return a DOM Element instead of a jQuery object you have to access the property in the position of `0` of the jQuery object. As follows: `$("element")[0]`. And that is why this **will** work:

```
var element1 = $("selector1")[0]; //accessing dom element 
var element2 = $("selector2")[0]; //from jQuery object
$([element1,element2])
```

Comment: +1 -- This is probably the most generic solution and thus the best answer since the question was a little ambiguous.

Comment: will accept this if you could explain me why "$([A,B,C,D]).each()" still works, but "$([A,B,C,D]).show()" doesn't ?

Comment: See my comment on namuol's question.

Comment: @vantrung-cuncon added some info on how jquery works, check it out

Comment: Sorry, but I still can not imagine what happens inside. The most important point is : what's the real essence of "$([A,B,C,D])", what it return ?

Comment: @vantrung-cuncon This is a general explanation of how it works, if you want to know what exactly happens inside i recommend you check jQuery's source code: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js and also give a check at the different javascript variable types.

Comment: You said "$([elem,elem2])" won't work, but it works flawlessly in this example : http://jsfiddle.net/Dw7Xu/ . So, I think there's something reasonable in namoul's answer. And the most important thing is that his way helped me. How weird?

Comment: @vantrung-cuncon It works when you use it with **each** that link has the same code i posted.

Comment: I think they're the same in essence: "$.each([A,B,C], fn)" and "$([A,B,C]).each(fn)". Just the different way of writing. Do u think so ? Anyway, your answer is the best. Accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have raw DOM elements (**not** jQuery objects such as `$('#abc')` or `$('.abc')`), there's no need to use `add`:

```
$([A,B,C,D]).show();
```

See the documentation of the [`$(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) function for details.

---

If you *really* want something like `$(A,B,C,D)` where `A,B,C,D` are jQuery objects, then the only real way is to roll your own function.

This does the trick:

```
var all = function() {
    var objs = $();
    $.each(arguments, function(i,e) {
        objs = objs.add(e);
    });
    return objs;
};

// ...

all(A,B,C,D).show();
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Jb6VD/5/

Comment: This doesn't work.  jQuery accepts a single jQuery object as an argument, but not an array of them.  It accepts an array of DOM elements, but not an array of jQuery objects.

Comment: @jfriend00: my answer specifically says assuming `A,B,C,D` is an array of DOM elements, **not** jQuery objects.

Comment: But, this is NOT an answer to the question at all.  The question states "While A,B,C,D are jQuery objects."   This would be more appropriate as a comment.  It is not an answer to the question asked.

Comment: I agree. That's why I left a comment initially (see my comment above) -- the asker then said "Oh that worked!" so I thought he just needed to correct his question. But now after some editing it looks like he really meant **jQuery objects**, so I'll probably delete this after the question cools off.

Comment: This is, anyway, a helpful post. I still wonder why this could work:
$([A,B,C,D]).each(function(){ ... })

Comment: `$.each` is a general utility function. It is not specifically expecting jQuery objects like `$.add`, so it works on any array-like object.

Comment: Not exactly. `$.each` performs its callback on each element of the array, and in this case, these elements happen to be jQuery objects, to which you can apply jQuery functions. In essence, it is the same as using whatever function you want for on each object. `$.each` does *not* go deeper into the array... if you log `this` inside the callback, you get multiple-elements jQuery objects, not single-element jQuery objects.

Comment: @FélixSaparelli, I merely said that `$.each` expects an array-like object. I said nothing about it flattening a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: @namuol, Yeah, I was clarifying for vantrung.

Comment: Not a bad solution. I hope this function will be intergrated in jquery's next update. Or they could upgrade the "add" function to accept more arguments than only one.

Comment: I hope I could accept more than 1 solution, to accept this one too.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the shortest version I could think of:

```
A.add([B[0], C[0], D[0]]).show();
```

This passes in an array of elements, rather than jQuery objects. Only works if `B`, `C`, and `D` are single-element arrays.

http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/Jb6VD/1/

Comment: That only gets the first DOM item out of B, C and D.  That's not a true union of A, B, C and D.

Comment: @jfriend00 - yes, and I noted that as a problem in my answer. Is that really worth a down-vote?

Answer (score 0):

To get the set resulting from the union of several jQuery objects (which are "just" arrays in a way), you can use `$.merge`:

```
var union = $.merge( $.merge(A,B), $.merge(C,D) );
```

`$.merge` only works on a pair of arrays, so using this on a large amount of jQuery objects would get very tiresome... in this case, you can use `$().get()` to obtain the "raw" array and `concat` them together:

```
var union = $([].concat(A.get(), B.get(), C.get(), ...));
// Assuming A, B, C... are jQuery objects
```

Comment: Yeah, as I said "simplest way", this answer is out of the circle. But since jQuery objects are all "raw arrays", why couldn't we join them by array's concat method ?

Comment: You can. I think `$.merge` is there for some weird compatibility issues... not sure.

Comment: I tried this, but `.concat()` doesn't work for jQuery objects: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/twcK5/ . If it did, you can have multiple arrays as arguments, so `A.concat(B,C,D)` would work... but it doesn't.

Comment: I think jquery object is not a raw array at all. We cannot use jqObj.concat(). But we can use : $([A].concat(B,C,D)) to return the same effect as "real array"

Comment: I never said a jQuery object was a *raw array* (`$() instanceof Array === false`), but that it was *array-like*: look at it in Firebug/Chrome console, it "looks" like an array. You can also use `$('a')[n]` to get the nth DOM element in the jQuery object. As a side note, you *can* get a raw array using `$('selector').get()`.